# Single file upload using Ajax, MVC 5 and jQuery

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload

I am using asp.net MVC 5 to do a simple single file upload using the  HTML element.I make an AJAX post request.The form has other fileds in addition to the file element.I tried diffrent methods available on the internet ,but nothing seems to be working.Is this really possible using the  element?Using a jQuery plugin is my last option.I like to make things simple in my application

my HTML

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Person", FormMethod.Post, new {  id = "form-person-edit-modal",  enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{    
    <div class="row">        
        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-4 columns">
                @Html.GenericInputFor(m => m.Name, Helpers.HtmlInputType.Text, new { id = "input-name" })
            </div>   

            <div class="small-4 columns">
                @Html.GenericInputFor(m => m.Description, Helpers.HtmlInputType.TextArea, new { id = "input-description" })
            </div>  
            <div class="small-4 columns">   
            <label>Choose File</label>
            <input type="file" name="attachment" id="attachment" />
            </div>          
        </div>       
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 columns">
            <input type="submit" id="image-submit" value="Save"/>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

-- C# ViewModel

```
 public class Person
 {
    Public string Name{get;set;}
    Public string Description{get;set;}
    public HttpPostedFileBase Attachment { get; set; }

 }
```

-- Jquery Ajax Post:

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            if (data.Success) {
                success(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
            } else {                
                if (error) {
                    error();
                }
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {            
            if (error)
                error();
        }

    });
```

-- Javacsript where I try to get the file content,before passing that data to the above method

```
function getData(){
       return {
          Name:$('#input-name').val(),
          Description:$('#input-description').val(),
          Attachment:$('#form-ticket-edit-modal').get(0).files[0]
       };
    }
```

But the Attachment on the controller is null.I tried this as below,but doesnt seem to be working

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Edit(ViewPerson person,HttpPostedFileBase attachment)
 {

 }
```

Is this still possible,or should I use a jQuery plugin(If so,which one do you recommend?)

Comment: This will work fine using a standard submit. If your using ajax, then your need to use `FormData` (HTML5) Refer [Sending files using a FormData object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects)

Comment: Thanks man.I changed the javacsript function from Attachment:$('#form-ticket-edit-modal').get(0).files[0]  to Attachment: getFileData() and getFileData:function(){
    
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append('attachment', $('#attachment').get(0).files[0]);        
        return data;
    } and was bale to see the Attachment as part of the viewmodel.But the only issue that I see is this only works with IE10 and later

Comment: Yes unfortunately `FormData` is only supported in modern browsers. I have seen ways this can be done without `FormData` but can't find the link. If I come across it I add a new comment.

Comment: Does anybody know whether I can do an Ajax single file upload with other form fields on the UI in a single HTTP POST request to the Asp.Net MVC controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used your code to show how to append image file,Please use Formdata() method to append your data and File and send through ajax.
Try Changing as per your requirement.

```js
$("#SubmitButtonID").on("click",function(){
var mydata=new Formdata();
mydata.append("Name",$("#name").val());
mydata.append("Image",Image.files[0]);
alert(mydata);
$.ajax({
        url: "@url.Action("ActionMethodName","ControllerName")",
        type: 'POST',
        contentType:false,
        processData;false,
        data: mydata,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            if (data.Success) {
                success(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
            } else {                
                if (error) {
                    error();
                }
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {            
            if (error)
                error();
        }

    });
    });
```

```html
    <input type="file" id="Image" name="file">
    <input type="button" id="SubmitButtonID" value="submit"/>
```

Comment: `FormData` is correct; don't spend 20 minutes wondering what's wrong like I just did.